# I get a TypeError when i try to list an array using a variable

Tags: python, arrays

What i am trying to do is create a card drawing program, but for whatever reason, I cannot use a variable to actually keep track of what list I should be using

```py
from random import shuffle
cards=list(['Ace of Spades','Spades 1','Spades 2','Spades 3','Spades 4','Spades 5','Spades 6','Spades 7','Spades 8', 'Spades 9','Spades 10', 'Jack of Spades','Queen of Spades','King of Spades','Ace of Diamonds','Diamonds 1','Diamonds 2', 'Diamonds 3','Diamonds 4', 'Diamonds 5', 'Diamonds 6', 'Diamonds 7', 'Diamonds 8', 'Diamonds 9', 'Diamonds 10','Jack of Diamonds', 'Queen of Diamonds', 'King of Diamonds', 'Ace of Clubs', 'Clubs 1','Clubs 2','Clubs 3', 'Clubs 4', 'Clubs 5', 'Clubs 6','Clubs 7', 'Clubs 8', 'Clubs 9', 'Clubs 10', 'Jack of Clubs','Queen of Clubs','King of Clubs', 'Ace of Hearts','Hearts 1', 'Hearts 2','Hearts 3', 'Hearts 4','Hearts 5','Hearts 6','Hearts 7', 'Hearts 8', 'Hearts 9','Hearts 10', 'Jack of Hearts', 'Queen of Hearts', 'King of Hearts'])
while True:
  order=0
  cards=shuffle(cards)
  while order !=53:
    if order==0:
      print('CURRENT CARD: '+cards[order])
      print('LAST CARD: -')
#OUTPUT
#TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable
```

Comment: Side note: you never increase `order` in the loop so it will loop forever.

Comment: I left that out of the code, Johnny

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
cards=shuffle(cards)
```

The value of cards is `None` as the shuffle should be in place (in the same list). When trying to get value by using below code, getting error as it is `None`.

```
print('CURRENT CARD: '+cards[order])
```

Below **working code** with simple iteration, change the logic as required:

```
import random

cards = ['Ace of Spades','Spades 1','Spades 2','Spades 3','Spades 4','Spades 5','Spades 6','Spades 7','Spades 8', 'Spades 9','Spades 10', 'Jack of Spades','Queen of Spades','King of Spades','Ace of Diamonds','Diamonds 1','Diamonds 2', 'Diamonds 3','Diamonds 4', 'Diamonds 5', 'Diamonds 6', 'Diamonds 7', 'Diamonds 8', 'Diamonds 9', 'Diamonds 10','Jack of Diamonds', 'Queen of Diamonds', 'King of Diamonds', 'Ace of Clubs', 'Clubs 1','Clubs 2','Clubs 3', 'Clubs 4', 'Clubs 5', 'Clubs 6','Clubs 7', 'Clubs 8', 'Clubs 9', 'Clubs 10', 'Jack of Clubs','Queen of Clubs','King of Clubs', 'Ace of Hearts','Hearts 1', 'Hearts 2','Hearts 3', 'Hearts 4','Hearts 5','Hearts 6','Hearts 7', 'Hearts 8', 'Hearts 9','Hearts 10', 'Jack of Hearts', 'Queen of Hearts', 'King of Hearts']
order = 0;
while True:
    random.shuffle(cards)
    print("current card:", cards[order])
    print("last card:", cards[(len(cards)-1)])
    order+1
```

**Output:**

```
...
current card: Diamonds 2
last card: King of Clubs
current card: Jack of Spades
last card: Spades 9
current card: Clubs 6
last card: Spades 10
current card: Diamonds 4
last card: Clubs 9
current card: Diamonds 6
last card: Spades 1
current card: Jack of Hearts
last card: Diamonds 3
current card: Spades 4
last card: Spades 1
current card: Jack of Clubs
last card: Clubs 4
current card: Spades 10
last card: Diamonds 8
current card: Spades 10
last card: Hearts 3
current card: Jack of Diamonds
last card: Diamonds 5
current card: Spades 1
...
```

Answer (score 0):

According to [the documentation for `shuffle()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.shuffle):

> Shuffle the sequence x in place.

So we should assume that the return value is `None` and `cards` is already shuffled. This means that you need to change

```
  cards=shuffle(cards)
```

to

```
  shuffle(cards)
```